# Unity3D with multiple jars (android jar + pure java lib)

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity3D and I have some projects already done with Java which need to be included in my Unity3D project.

I want to add multiple jars into Unity3D project but it looks like jars are not have any dependency between them when they are running in Unity project.

For this,

- I tried to add all the jars related in Assets/Plugins/Android folder (Multiple some pure java jar files in the folder with an Android jar to invoke the methods of jars)
- I tried to make only one jar file (By creating an Android project with all the jars included)

With these 2 methods, I can build my project as Android based, but they showed errors say related library is not exist

Is there any way I can use multiple jar library into Unity3D project with dependency to other jars?

In other words, I want this structure

| Main Project(Unity) | --dependency--> | Jar lib 1 | --dependency--> | Jar lib 2 |

- Jar lib 1: Library I need to call method directly
- Jar lib 2: A library which lib 1 uses

Comment: I would be inclined to just **forget about it**.  it's just not what Unity is for.  You're making a huge amount of pain for no gain at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I can use multiple jar library into Unity3D project
> with dependency to other jars?

**NO**.

If you have many jar libraries that depend on each other, you have to combine them into one. Yes, the jars must be merged into one, then you can make a bridge that Unity can use to access them.

> Jar lib 1: Library I need to call method directly
>
> Jar lib 2: A library which lib 1 uses

In this scenario, you have to import the **Lib 2** in **Lib 1**. Then make functions in **Lib 1** that calls functions in Jar **Lib 2**. You can then build **Lib 1** and **Lib 2**.

In Eclipse, **Projects**->**Build All**. Then export them both into one jar file. Again, in Eclipse, **File**->**Export...**->**Java**->**JAR file**. Next, then select both Libs if they show up. Use the settings below:

[image]

**Java:**

//Stuff from Lib/Jar **2** (Lets assume this is the function code in it)

```
public class Lib2{
    public static Lib2 instance = new Lib2();

    public double getRandomNumber() {
        double advancedRandomNumber = 5;
        return advancedRandomNumber;
    }
}
```

//Stuff from Lib/Jar **1** (**com.roxy.app**) package (Lets assume this is the function code in it)

```
public class Lib1{
    public static Lib1 instance = new Lib1();

    public double getMagicRandomNumber() {
        double advancedRandomNumber = 15;
        return advancedRandomNumber;
    }

   //Bridge to access Stuff from jar 2
   public double getExtraMagicRandomNumber()
   {
        return Lib2.instance.getRandomNumber();
   }
}
```

**C#:**

```
  private AndroidJavaClass androidClass;
  private AndroidJavaObject androidFunction;

  #if UNITY_ANDROID
        if (androidClass == null || androidFunction == null)
        {
            androidClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.roxy.app.Lib1");
            androidFunction = androidClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
        }
  #endif
```

Then you can call `getMagicRandomNumber()` function from `Lib1` with:

```
double adRand = androidFunction.Call<double>("getMagicRandomNumber");
```

And call function from `Lib2` from the bridged function made in `Lib1`.

```
double adRand = androidFunction.Call<double>("getExtraMagicRandomNumber");
```

That's it. It's not hard but this may **not** compile because I typed it directly to this Editor. Minor modification may need to be made.