# Using implement an AndroidJavaClass in unity

Tags: java, unity-game-engine

I have a java object that gets a listener object as a parameter. This listener should implement a certain java abstract class.

I'm trying to prevent writing this in java, because I use an SDK that comes in a jar file, and to call a jar file from a java file, I'll need to create one jar file that includes them both (see [Unity3D with multiple jars (android jar + pure java lib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200097/unity3d-with-multiple-jars-android-jar-pure-java-lib))

This answer explains my error but doesn't give a solution.
[AndroidJavaProxy is not an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44930973/androidjavaproxy-is-not-an-interface)

I'll try to be more detailed:
I've got the Listener class (which is inside the jar file):

```java
public abstract class AttachCallback {
  public AttachCallback();
  public void onAttached(Sdk sdk);
}
```

My c# code is currently (and doesn't work):

```cs
public class AttachCallback : AndroidJavaProxy
{
    public AttachCallback() : base("com.example.AttachCallback")
    {
    }

    public void onAttached(AndroidJavaObject sdk)
    {
      Debug.Log("-----Attached------");
    }
}
```

Currently, I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.example.AttachCallback is not an interface`

So, is there a way to do this?
Thanks in advance,
Chaim

Answer (score 0):

First: read this [article](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaProxy.html). Android Java Proxy can implement only interfaces. So you should create interface in java. Something like:

```
public interface IAttachable
{
    public void onAttached(Sdk sdk);
}
```

In your AttachCallback class you add this interface like:

```
public abstract class AttachCallback implements IAttachable {
    public IAttachable unityCallback;
    public void onAttached(String sdk) 
    {
        unityCallback.onAttached(sdk);
    }
}
```

Then in your unity class, create JavaProxy

```
public class AttachCallback : AndroidJavaProxy
{
    public AttachCallback() : base("com.example.IAttachable")
    {
    }

    public void onAttached(AndroidJavaObject sdk)
    {
      Debug.Log("-----Attached------");
    }
}
```

For attaching your Unity Proxy you should pass your AttachCallback to java, something like:

```
public void AddAttachToJava()
{
    AttachCallback callback = new AttachCallback();
    //Passing to activity, but you can do whatever you want
    using (AndroidJavaClass javaClass = new AndroidJavaClass("your activity class name"))
    {
        using (AndroidJavaObject activity = javaClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("mContext"))
        {
            activity.Call("attachUnityCallback", callback);
        }
    }
}
```

Your java method in activity should look like this:

```
public void attachUnityCallback(IAttachable attachable)
{
    // if AttachCallback is created
    attachCallback.unityCallback = attachable;
    attachCallback.onAttached(sdk);
}
```

Comment: This requires being able to change the listener definition. What if it's some built in API listener like https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/OnObbStateChangeListener ?

Comment: you should implement your own class with both interfaces and register it in unity

Comment: is it possible to do that without writing a plugin?